# css layout issue: arranging a layout with css containing ul

Tags: css, layout

I am trying to arrange a container in inline but seems like missing something in my css.
Seems like class="second" does not work after using float:right . 
My container looks like

```
<nav id="main">
  <a>First</a>
  <ul></ul>
  <a>Second</a>
</nav>
```

Seems like I am missing something in my CSS

My jsfiddle link :  http://jsfiddle.net/pttVq/1/

Comment: This article might help http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, UL needs to be inline too... since it is a block element by default.

```
ul {display: inline;}
```

However, that probably won't get you the effect you are looking for. Try floating the ul left as well.

```
ul {float: left;}
```

Comment: Thanks seems like ul, a{float:left;} fix the issue .

Comment: Glad to be of help. :) Don't forget to set it as the accepted answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

why dont you make it like this

```
<nav id="main">

    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#" class="first">First</a></li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li><a href="#" class="second">Second</a></li>        
    </ul>

</nav>
```

see it in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pttVq/4/)

and removing borders

```
li:nth-of-type(1), li:nth-last-of-type(1){
 border:none;
}
```

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pttVq/7/)

Comment: there is limitation since I am generating all this content dynamically and this will create issue with my ul items . I need to keep them separate.